# Centered a fixed container over bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, centering

I have a fullscreen version of bootstrap carousel working very nicely.

However, I would like to centre a div containing three icons horizontally and vertically and have it fixed over the sliding carousel images.

I have tried setting a width for the class:

```
.centered {
  position:fixed; 
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;

 }
```

However, the three icons do not more from the top left.

Here is the link to the site if you would like to inspect my HTML code:

http://www.gregorydanelian.comule.com/stu/

Many thanks coders!

Comment: A fixed position requires the x y position and height and width.

Comment: Yes. I have tried this, yet it does not centre within the document window, it is too far to the right. `.centered {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 100;  
  top:50%;  
  left:50%;  
  width: 500px;    
  height:200px;
 }`

Comment: It will center within the width and height. Look at: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/ and read entire post

Comment: Thank you, it's fixed and remains reponsive. Will post answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute/fixed centering:

```
  .parent {
     position: relative;
  }
  .centered {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: auto;
     width: 500px;
     height: 200px;
 }
```

With this method you will center horizontal and vertical. The downside is that you will need fixed width and height of the centered element.

Here is the version with `position: fixed;` http://jsfiddle.net/ngP8f/

Good luck!